# JS Auto fill data in table next line

Tags: javascript, onchange, autofill

I have table #TablePopupStopPlanUnplan and have 1-8 StopPlan lines

the system will generate row for all StopPlan in line, when user input information on first row system will copy data from first row to all automatically.

How to fill data automatic. I think on change is not work because it same table.
The number of StopPlan lines is not constant, sometimes it's 1, meaning it doesn't have to be automatic, sometimes it's 8.

StopPlan1 1 1 2
StopPlan2 1 1 2
StopPlan3 1 1 2

Comment: the question is very unclear. Can you please share the table you are having issues with and the logic generating those rows? But more importantly what's the exact problem? just creating a new line to stack in an already existing table element?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: table like  1 1 2 I want auto fill like 1 1 2 , 1 1 2, 1 1 2 in other row